# Is there a cross-reference guide?

Tags: set-database, part-database

Is there a database that will tell you what possible sets you are able to build based on the sets you already own, sort of a cross reference guide?

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE! I've closed this question as it appears to be a duplicate of one of our previous questions. Hopefully the answers there meet your needs. If there is anything else that we can help with, feel free to ask other questions!